# Query the size of all tables in Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

I want to be able to query and filter tables based on it's size

I already know sp_spaceused, but it shows the size for one table at a time

Answer (score 8):

Here's [that view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview#table-size-queries) adjusted to use `sys.pdw_permanent_table_mappings` as per the Synapse recommendation

```
SELECT two_part_name, SUM( row_count ) AS row_count, SUM( reserved_space_GB ) AS reserved_space_GB
FROM dbo.vTableSizes
GROUP BY two_part_name
ORDER BY reserved_space_GB DESC;
```

The view:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.vTableSizes
AS
WITH base
AS
(
SELECT
 GETDATE()                                                             AS  [execution_time]
, DB_NAME()                                                            AS  [database_name]
, s.name                                                               AS  [schema_name]
, t.name                                                               AS  [table_name]
, QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(t.name)                              AS  [two_part_name]
, nt.[name]                                                            AS  [node_table_name]
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nt.[name] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     AS  [node_table_name_seq]
, tp.[distribution_policy_desc]                                        AS  [distribution_policy_name]
, c.[name]                                                             AS  [distribution_column]
, nt.[distribution_id]                                                 AS  [distribution_id]
, i.[type]                                                             AS  [index_type]
, i.[type_desc]                                                        AS  [index_type_desc]
, nt.[pdw_node_id]                                                     AS  [pdw_node_id]
, pn.[type]                                                            AS  [pdw_node_type]
, pn.[name]                                                            AS  [pdw_node_name]
, di.name                                                              AS  [dist_name]
, di.position                                                          AS  [dist_position]
, nps.[partition_number]                                               AS  [partition_nmbr]
, nps.[reserved_page_count]                                            AS  [reserved_space_page_count]
, nps.[reserved_page_count] - nps.[used_page_count]                    AS  [unused_space_page_count]
, nps.[in_row_data_page_count]
    + nps.[row_overflow_used_page_count]
    + nps.[lob_used_page_count]                                        AS  [data_space_page_count]
, nps.[reserved_page_count]
 - (nps.[reserved_page_count] - nps.[used_page_count])
 - ([in_row_data_page_count]
         + [row_overflow_used_page_count]+[lob_used_page_count])       AS  [index_space_page_count]
, nps.[row_count]                                                      AS  [row_count]
from
    sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
    ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
    ON  t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
    AND i.[index_id] <= 1
INNER JOIN sys.pdw_table_distribution_properties tp
    ON t.[object_id] = tp.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.pdw_permanent_table_mappings tm
    ON t.[object_id] = tm.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.pdw_nodes_tables nt
    ON tm.[physical_name] = nt.[name]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_pdw_nodes pn
    ON  nt.[pdw_node_id] = pn.[pdw_node_id]
INNER JOIN sys.pdw_distributions di
    ON  nt.[distribution_id] = di.[distribution_id]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats nps
    ON nt.[object_id] = nps.[object_id]
    AND nt.[pdw_node_id] = nps.[pdw_node_id]
    AND nt.[distribution_id] = nps.[distribution_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from sys.pdw_column_distribution_properties where distribution_ordinal = 1) cdp
    ON t.[object_id] = cdp.[object_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON cdp.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    AND cdp.[column_id] = c.[column_id]
WHERE pn.[type] = 'COMPUTE'
)
, size
AS
(
SELECT
   [execution_time]
,  [database_name]
,  [schema_name]
,  [table_name]
,  [two_part_name]
,  [node_table_name]
,  [node_table_name_seq]
,  [distribution_policy_name]
,  [distribution_column]
,  [distribution_id]
,  [index_type]
,  [index_type_desc]
,  [pdw_node_id]
,  [pdw_node_type]
,  [pdw_node_name]
,  [dist_name]
,  [dist_position]
,  [partition_nmbr]
,  [reserved_space_page_count]
,  [unused_space_page_count]
,  [data_space_page_count]
,  [index_space_page_count]
,  [row_count]
,  ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0)                                 AS [reserved_space_KB]
,  ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0)/1000                            AS [reserved_space_MB]
,  ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0)/1000000                         AS [reserved_space_GB]
,  ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0)/1000000000                      AS [reserved_space_TB]
,  ([unused_space_page_count]   * 8.0)                                 AS [unused_space_KB]
,  ([unused_space_page_count]   * 8.0)/1000                            AS [unused_space_MB]
,  ([unused_space_page_count]   * 8.0)/1000000                         AS [unused_space_GB]
,  ([unused_space_page_count]   * 8.0)/1000000000                      AS [unused_space_TB]
,  ([data_space_page_count]     * 8.0)                                 AS [data_space_KB]
,  ([data_space_page_count]     * 8.0)/1000                            AS [data_space_MB]
,  ([data_space_page_count]     * 8.0)/1000000                         AS [data_space_GB]
,  ([data_space_page_count]     * 8.0)/1000000000                      AS [data_space_TB]
,  ([index_space_page_count]  * 8.0)                                   AS [index_space_KB]
,  ([index_space_page_count]  * 8.0)/1000                              AS [index_space_MB]
,  ([index_space_page_count]  * 8.0)/1000000                           AS [index_space_GB]
,  ([index_space_page_count]  * 8.0)/1000000000                        AS [index_space_TB]
FROM base
)
SELECT *
FROM size
;
```

Comment: This view looks cool, but no query finishes, its been 40 minutes since a top 10 *

Comment: I am using 7500dwu

Comment: Could be a concurrency thing, is the server very busy?  May be worth trying without the TOP 10, trying as a user with a higher resource class etc

Comment: There are no queued queries, my WG can use 60% of resources and at the moment, the overall resource utilization is close to 50%... weird

Comment: Have you tried without Top 10?  I suppose it’s worth trying the original view too.

Comment: If those don't work, then I'd suggest raising a ticket.  This is after all, Microsoft published documentation so it should be correct, and functional.  Posting back the resolution to any issues you resolve would also be helpful to the community.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [documented DMV queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview?#table-size-queries) allow you to get a report of all table sizes.